# From JSON String to Java Object using javax.json

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'm using the `com.google.gson.Gson` API to convert a JSON string to a Java object:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
User u = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
```

I'd like to know if there's an equivalent API in **javax.json** api to do the equivalent.
Thanks!

Comment: It's possible, but very definitely not with an oneliner. You'll need help of Java Beans Introspector API. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable (using only JSON API calls).

Answer (score 9):

This is definitely not possible with an oneliner like as with Gson. The `javax.json` API is very low level. It only returns you a JSON object structure which you've to breakdown and map to a javabean further all by yourself.

In order to achieve (nearly) the same effect as `Gson#fromJson()`, here's a kickoff example of the boilerplate code. Parameterized types and javabeans are supported to certain extent. It's all standard Java SE API, the javabeans are introspected with little help of `java.beans` API.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> beanClass) {
    JsonValue value = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json)).read();
    return (T) decode(value, beanClass);
}

private static Object decode(JsonValue jsonValue, Type targetType) {
    if (jsonValue.getValueType() == ValueType.NULL) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (jsonValue.getValueType() == ValueType.TRUE || jsonValue.getValueType() == ValueType.FALSE) {
        return decodeBoolean(jsonValue, targetType);
    }
    else if (jsonValue instanceof JsonNumber) {
        return decodeNumber((JsonNumber) jsonValue, targetType);
    }
    else if (jsonValue instanceof JsonString) {
        return decodeString((JsonString) jsonValue, targetType);
    }
    else if (jsonValue instanceof JsonArray) {
        return decodeArray((JsonArray) jsonValue, targetType);
    }
    else if (jsonValue instanceof JsonObject) {
        return decodeObject((JsonObject) jsonValue, targetType);
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported json value: " + jsonValue);
    }
}

private static Object decodeBoolean(JsonValue jsonValue, Type targetType) {
    if (targetType == boolean.class || targetType == Boolean.class) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(jsonValue.toString());
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported boolean type: " + targetType);
    }
}

private static Object decodeNumber(JsonNumber jsonNumber, Type targetType) {
    if (targetType == int.class || targetType == Integer.class) {
        return jsonNumber.intValue();
    }
    else if (targetType == long.class || targetType == Long.class) {
        return jsonNumber.longValue();
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported number type: " + targetType);
    }
}

private static Object decodeString(JsonString jsonString, Type targetType) {
    if (targetType == String.class) {
        return jsonString.getString();
    }
    else if (targetType == Date.class) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(jsonString.getString()); // This is default Gson format. Alter if necessary.
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported date format: " + jsonString.getString());
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported string type: " + targetType);
    }
}

private static Object decodeArray(JsonArray jsonArray, Type targetType) {
    Class<?> targetClass = (Class<?>) ((targetType instanceof ParameterizedType) ? ((ParameterizedType) targetType).getRawType() : targetType);

    if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(targetClass)) {
        Class<?> elementClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) targetType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (JsonValue item : jsonArray) {
            list.add(decode(item, elementClass));
        }

        return list;
    }
    else if (targetClass.isArray()) {
        Class<?> elementClass = targetClass.getComponentType();
        Object array = Array.newInstance(elementClass, jsonArray.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            Array.set(array, i, decode(jsonArray.get(i), elementClass));
        }

        return array;
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported array type: " + targetClass);
    }
}

private static Object decodeObject(JsonObject object, Type targetType) {
    Class<?> targetClass = (Class<?>) ((targetType instanceof ParameterizedType) ? ((ParameterizedType) targetType).getRawType() : targetType);

    if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(targetClass)) {
        Class<?> valueClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) targetType).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Entry<String, JsonValue> entry : object.entrySet()) {
            map.put(entry.getKey(), decode(entry.getValue(), valueClass));
        }

        return map;
    }
    else try {
        Object bean = targetClass.newInstance();

        for (PropertyDescriptor property : Introspector.getBeanInfo(targetClass).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            if (property.getWriteMethod() != null && object.containsKey(property.getName())) {
                property.getWriteMethod().invoke(bean, decode(object.get(property.getName()), property.getWriteMethod().getGenericParameterTypes()[0]));
            }
        }

        return bean;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported object type: " + targetClass, e);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
User u = YourJsonUtil.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
```

In case you're seeing an `UnsupportedOperationException` coming from one of `decodeXxx()` methods, just add the desired conversion logic to the method in question. Of course this could be refactored further to apply the strategy pattern and such so that it's flexible and extensible, but then we're basically reinventing Gson.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

And before you try other parsers then GSON: org.json is buggy/has implementation mistakes. QuickJson is buggy/has implementation mistakes